# Swift: SKEmitterNode affected by PhysicsWorld gravity?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to have a rain particles which are affected by wind aka physicsWorld gravity.

I can see that the gravity does has an affect on my SKSpriteNodes but I can't achieve the same affect on an SKEmitterNode.

I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Here's what I've been trying...

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    if let rainParticles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Rain.sks") {
        rainParticles.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height)
        rainParticles.name = "rainParticle"
        rainParticles.targetNode = scene
        rainParticles.particlePositionRange = 
                CGVector(dx: frame.size.width, dy: frame.size.height)
        rainParticles.zPosition = -1

        // I don't think this is right
        rainParticles.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
        rainParticles.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        addChild(rainParticles)
    }

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    // gravity is pushing to the right here
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 0)
    physicsWorld.speed = 0.85
}
```

Yes I have added `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`.

Obviously I want to ignore collisions so I haven't set `collisionBitMask`, also I don't want to have rain bouncing off anything with `contactTestBitMask`. I don't believe I need to set a `categoryBitMask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Particles are not represented by objects in SpriteKit. This means you cannot perform node-related tasks on particles, nor can you associate physics bodies with particles to make them interact with other content. Although there is no visible class representing particles added by the emitter node, you can think of a particle as having properties like any other object.

This is straight from `SKEmitterNode` documentation. Particles won't get any gravity acceleration from the `physicsWorld` of the scene.
Also `rainParticles.physicsBody` refers to the SKEmitterNode `physicsBody`, not its particles.

If you simply want the particles to simulate the current `physicsWorld`'s gravity:

```
rainParticles.xAcceleration = self.physicsWorld.gravity.dx
rainParticles.yAcceleration = self.physicsWorld.gravity.dy
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, your particles are not effected by physics fields, but you can change that with the `fieldBitMask`

I added a radial gravity field (you could use a linear one)

```
    let fieldNode = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField();
    fieldNode.position = center
    fieldNode.falloff = 0;
    fieldNode.strength = -0.03;
    fieldNode.animationSpeed = 5;
    fieldNode.categoryBitMask = 1
```

then in my emitter node, I simply set `fieldBitMask = 1`

```
class MyNode:SKEmitterNode{
    
    override init() {
  
        super.init()

        //Snip   

        fieldBitMask = 1
    }

}
```